# invalid_grant error while getting access token via OAuth 2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth, oauth-2.0

There is a python app uses [Health Graph API](http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/getting-started)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from main.settings import CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, RUNKEEPER_LOGIN_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
import requests


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def login(request):
    code = request.GET['code']
    post_data = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                 'code': code,
                 'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                 'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                 'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/welcome/'}

    req = requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, data=post_data)
```

My login button that redirects user to Health Graph Login Page and let's my app wait authorization code.

```
<a href="https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Flogin&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxx">
```

When I try to get access token by calling login function, I getting 'invalid grant' error as request. I tried to replace 'authorization_code' to another words and I've got another 'unsupported grant type' error. Another words, token server refuses code that I getting from auth server. What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` used in the redirect to the authorization endpoint differs from the one that you use in the `login` function that exchanges the `code` at the token endpoint. As the docs at http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/getting-started ("Connect your Application to a User's Health Graph Account", bullet 3.) stipulate, it should match exactly:

> redirect_uri: The exact URL that you supplied when sending the user to
>   the authorization endpoint above